# How do I get Lotus Symphony 3.0 working?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I have recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.I did so under the impression that Lotus Symphony would function on this operating system.

I have done about everything I can think of - including a force install of the i386 package, to trying dylan's symphony package found on OMGubuntu.

Both of these did install it and bring up and agreement screen. I accepted the terms and it doesn't open the program. The Icon of the program when opened is a gray question mark box, then it closes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I know about LibreOffice, and I know that it is functional on 64 bit, but I find symphony to have a far superior UI. So all though that would be an alternative I don't feel as though that is a solution to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ibm-office-suite-lotus-symphony-3-released/ and http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/lotus-symphony-fix-pack-ubuntu-64bit/ ? (I know you say you have "trying dylan's symphony package found on OMGubuntu" but which one?

Answer (score 2):

First, try the package someone else has [already done for you](http://www.photofiltre-lx.org/lotus_symphony3_fp1.amd64.deb).

If not, then you'll have to pretend you're on 32bit.

Start by running the following in the terminal, providing your password when prompted.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

[Downloading Lotus Symphony 3.0.1](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-20%2013:09:15.407644R) (choose language, login, accept terms).
Then run this, replacing Downloads/your-package.deb with the actual package location and name.

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i Downloads/your-package.deb
```

You may also want to [Download Lotus Symphony 3.0.1 (Fix Pack 3)](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/preconfig.jsp?id=2010-10-19%2016:31:30.675440R), and install that in the same way.